# Firebase Rate Limiting

Tags: firebase, loading, database-performance, angularfire

I'm currently experiencing huge load times with Firebase.  I have about 5,000 entries in a "users" collection, and it was working fine until I added a base64-encoded photo to each user.  Here's a summary of the code:

```
function initCurrentAuth() {
    return authRef.$requireAuth().then(attachUserObject);
}
function attachUserObject(authData) {

    getUser(authData.uid).$loaded().then(function(user) {
        ...this code never runs because getUser never resolves
    }
}
function getUser(id) { 
    userReference = usersRef.child(id);
    return $firebaseObject(userReference);
}
```

I'm on the free firebase plan, so I'm wondering if I'm being throttled?  If anyone has any insights, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How big is each image? Multiple that by 5000 and then by the number of clients you have connected to the database. What's the bandwidth you're using with that?

Comment: The images are generally in the 10-100kb range, so 50MB - 500MB.  This is a staging database, so there only 3 users connected.  I'm confused, though - I thought bandwidth was the amount of data transferred.  A user connected to the database shouldn't have to download every photo to access their own photo, right?

Comment: That depends on your code. If you have a listener on `users` (e.g. to show a list of user names) and the photo of each user is under there, it'll download all of them.

Comment: There isn't any watch on the users collection.  However, looking at the analytics page, we've used 61.22 GB of bandwidth in the last 30 days...yikes, that's a lot.  Would this be the culprit?

Comment: Downloading images is certainly going to be a major contributor to bandwidth usage. You can easily see what goes over the wire for each client by opening the Chrome developer console and checking the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone else, but just in case - as Frank suggested, we did have a "listener".  I had been looking for a $watch in the code that would trigger it, but we had a $firebaseObject(users) call which triggered the massive download.